# Issues with Flume HDFS sink from Twitter

Tags: twitter, hdfs, flume, sink

I currently have this configuration in Flume :

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
# The configuration file needs to define the sources,
# the channels and the sinks.
# Sources, channels and sinks are defined per agent,
# in this case called 'TwitterAgent'
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = YPTxqtRamIZ1bnJXYwGW
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = Wjyw9714OBzao7dktH0csuTByk4iLG9Zu4ddtI6s0ho
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = 2340010790-KhWiNLt63GuZ6QZNYuPMJtaMVjLFpiMP4A2v
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = x1pVVuyxfvaTbPoKvXqh2r5xUA6tf9einoByLIL8rar
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://hadoop1:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

The twitter app auth keys are correct.
And I keep getting this error in the flume log file:

```
ERROR   org.apache.flume.SinkRunner     

Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop1
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:446)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop1
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:353)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:194)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:227)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:221)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$8$1.run(BucketWriter.java:589)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.runPrivileged(BucketWriter.java:161)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.access$800(BucketWriter.java:57)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$8.call(BucketWriter.java:586)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop1
    ... 23 more
```

Does any one here knows why and could explain it to me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Exception, the problem is that the host hadoop1 is unknown.

according to the flume configuration file the path you have given is

```
hdfs://hadoop1:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
```

which is supposed to be accessible from the machine with the flume agent. since machine names cannot be used to access the HDFS without being in the same domain, you need to access the HDFS using the IP address as set in `core-site.xml`

Comment: @AntariskshaYelkawar Great, it works. The file is **core-site.xml**. Thanks.

Comment: where is the IP address set in the core-site.xml file?